# Example of a Django query set

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I would like to have an example of a django query that allows you to select elements contained in two different tables in a database in a single query

```
data = Insuree.objects.filter(gender = 'F').count()
data2 = Service.objects.filter(code = 'F4').count()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can combine queries with the | character.

```
data = Insuree.objects.filter(gender = 'F').count() | Service.objects.filter(code = 'F4').count()
```